# SelectList ingoring selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code to populate a `DropDownList`

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
list.Add("1.000.000", 1000000m);
list.Add("500.000", 500000m);
list.Add("5.000", 5000m);
viewModel.MyValue = 500000.00m; //of type decimal?
viewModel.MyList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Key", viewModel.MyValue);
```

While in the Html

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyValue, Model.MyList, "select value")
```

All works fine (the selected value is passed to the controller and saved regularly), the only thing not working is the selected value. The one I pass is not automatically selected in the dropdown. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hmm, strange, I tried copy pasting your code and even if you make everything strings or ints it still doesn't select the list value.

Comment: That's right. I also tried to use `viewModel.MyValue.ToString()` to see if there is some weird behaviour, but nothing. And I use it all the time with List<T> without problems. Guess I have to make a project from scratch and see if I can resolve this issue.

Comment: ...And then I copy pasted it in a new project and it worked verbatim. Now I have no idea what to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. 
The framework while doing the ToString() in the SelectList was unable to match 500000.00 with 500000 (I put the wrong value in my question, sorry for the typo. updated)

Using a simple froeach you can see what happen

```
  viewModel.MyList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Key", viewModel.MyValue);
  foreach (var item in viewModel.MyList)
  {
    var p = viewModel.MyValue.ToString();
    if (item.Value == p) //here 500000 != 500000.00
    {
      item.Selected = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

So I solve the problem simply doing

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
list.Add("1.000.000", 1000000.00m);
list.Add("500.000", 500000.00m);
list.Add("5.000", 5000.00m);
```

Thanks all for the help anyway